# How to get left alignment of column contents

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }

b)radius $3.5$ cm       &Area= $38.5 \ cm^2$                &circumference $= 22$ cm \\ % ok
c)diameter $56$ cm      &Area =$2464 \ cm^2$                &circumference $= 176$ cm \\ % ok
d)diameter $49$ cm      &Area= $1886.5 \  cm^2$                 &circumference  $= 154$ cm\\ % ok
e)radius $1.5x$ cm      &Area =$\tfrac{99}{14}x^2 \  cm^2$      &circumference $= \frac{66}{7} x $ cm\\
f)diameter $28x$ cm     &Area= $616x^2  \ cm^2$             &circumference $= 88 x$ cm % ok
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question and add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). As it is currently written, it is unclear what you are looking for.

Comment: The small letter b just wont lined up some spacing issue

Comment: I dont understand left justify

Comment: You have a table with three columns that all are centered. I you want to get left-aligned cells, dont use `c c c`, but `l l l`. Sorry, I don't understand what the result should look like.

Comment: Thanks You done it. I should use letter l for left . Not c for centre

Comment: Please, don't teach children that pi is 22/7. It's wrong and very misleading.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to switching from the `c` (center) to the `l` (left) column type, you should aim to improve the visual appeal of the table. In particular, all repeated matter (such as the words "radius"/"diameter", "area", and "circumference") should be moved out of the body of the table and into the header. Providing some visual structure -- such as placing the column labels and the units of measurement on separate rows -- would also be welcome. Take a look at the following "before and after" juxtaposition. Oh, and for the first data column, please select either "radius" or "diameter", but don't jump back and forth between the two concepts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\tfrac' macro
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for '\unit' macro
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{array}    % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}} % left-aligned & automatic inline math mode

\begin{document}

``before'' 

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{ c c c }
b)radius $3.5$ cm       &Area= $38.5 \ cm^2$   &circumference $= 22$ cm \\ % ok
c)diameter $56$ cm      &Area =$2464 \ cm^2$   &circumference $= 176$ cm \\ % ok
d)diameter $49$ cm      &Area= $1886.5 \  cm^2$    &circumference  $= 154$ cm\\ % ok
e)radius $1.5x$ cm      &Area =$\tfrac{99}{14}x^2 \  cm^2$   &circumference $= \frac{66}{7} x $ cm\\
f)diameter $28x$ cm     &Area= $616x^2  \ cm^2$   &circumference $= 88 x$ cm % ok
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
``after''

\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{@{} l LLL @{}}
 & \text{radius} & \text{area} & \text{circumference} \\
 & (\unit{\centi\meter}) & (\unit{\centi\meter\squared}) & (\unit{cm}) \\
\midrule
b) & 3.5  & 38.5             & 22  \\ 
c) & 28   & 2464             & 176 \\ 
d) & 24.5   & 1886.5           & 154 \\ 
e) & 1.5x & \frac{99}{14}x^2 & \frac{66}{7}x  \\
f) & 14x  & 616x^2           & 88 x 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could even align the numbers at the decimal points, although it may look a bit strange since there are also variables and common fractions.

Comment: @JasperHabicht - Thanks. I did think about it. However, since the OP's main question was about left-aligning cell contents, I decided to stick with `l`.

Comment: Heading a column "radius" ignores the fact that in some rows, it says "diameter".  This changes the meaning.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for noticing this issue. I've standardized the second table on radii.

Comment: All good now many thanks